# Comparing time column in 2 different books and get number of records

Tags: sql

I am quite new to SQL and I am trying to find the number of records for the same ship_name. Below is an example of my current data.

Book 1

```html
time_column_1   ship_name   ship_arrival_time number_of_records
27/3/2017  4:00  TOMY          28/3/2017 8:00        0
27/3/2017  8:00  TOMY          28/3/2017 8:00        3
27/3/2017  12:00 TOMY          28/3/2017 8:00        4
27/3/2017  16:00 TOMY          28/3/2017 8:00        7
27/3/2017  16:00 HX            28/3/2017 8:00        0
```

Book2

```html
arrival_time_of_containers   ship_name
27/3/2017 6:00                TOMY
27/3/2017 7:00                TOMY
27/3/2017 8:00                TOMY
27/3/2017 10:00               TOMY
27/3/2017 13:00               TOMY
27/3/2017 13:00               TOMY
```

Above are examples of my data for 2 books that I have. I am trying to compare the arrival_time_of_container in book 2 against time_column_1 in book 1 and trying to get the number_of_records_column.

The number_of_records_column should not increase until the arrival_time_of_container column matches time_column_1, getting all the records before that in total.

Do you have any suggestions?

```html
SELECT distinct ship_name, ship_arrival_time, time_column_1, arrival_time_of_containers, count(case when arrival_time_of_containers <= time_column_1 AND ship_name = ship_name then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_records
from [Book1] p
INNER JOIN [Book2] ON p.primary_key = [Book2].primary_key
group by p.ship_name, p.ship_arrival_time, p.time_column_1, [Book2].arrival_time_of_containers
order by p.time_column_1 asc
```

So far I have come up with this bunch of code, but the values for the number_of_records column is still not proper, it does not count according to how I want it to be.

This is my result so far.

```html
ship_name   ship_arrival_time     time_column_1   
          
  TOMY      2017-03-23 14:05:00 2017-03-23 12:00:00
  TOMY      2017-03-23 14:05:00 2017-03-23 12:00:00
  TOMY      2017-03-23 14:05:00 2017-03-23 12:00:00
  TOMY      2017-03-23 14:05:00 2017-03-23 12:00:00
  TOMY      2017-03-23 14:05:00 2017-03-23 12:00:00        
  
  arrival_time_of_containers  number_of_records
    2017-03-21 15:13:00               5
    2017-03-21 15:22:00               5
    2017-03-21 15:30:00               5
    2017-03-21 16:02:00               5
    2017-03-21 16:13:00               5
```

Comment: Is this about SQL Server, Access or Excel? You can't just tag everything in the world and expect people to know what you're asking.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: What dbms is this?  The syntax, especially date/time functions are very different between dbms.  No one can help you unless you specify which dbms you are using.

Comment: Hi, I believe that this is in an rdbms